# Hot redeploy files in web fragment project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, war, hotdeploy, web-fragment

I have a project with different modules. In fact, I have 4 modules:

- **presentation-jsf**
- **repository-oracle**
- **service**
- **webapp**

See the image below:

[image]

I am developing a library to use by another teams of the company I am working at. For that reason, we can not add the xhtml files in the webapp module. We decide that because as a library we want to keep in that way. 
We are using **Primefaces 6.1** with the **Barcelona theme**. Also, I am using JSF2 with Tomcat.

The WebApp is totally empty because are the clients who will be using it in theirs webapps. For that reason, the module where I have the .xhtml files is **presentation-jsf**. Inside there, I have all the **xhtml** files:

[image]

The problem is that when I am executing the **webapp** itself, without any client, the application is working fine (I can access to the **http://localhost/web/app/view.xhtml** file). I don't need any of my client's project to use the library. I can use it directly as a webapp. But the main problem is that I can not do a hot redeploy. It means that all the files with xhtml format, is not working.

Of course, when I am using any of my clients, the application is not doing any hot redeploy because they are using it as a **war file (library)**. For that reason, I suppouse that is not possible to do a hot deploy.

I am using **Intellij**. For that reason, maybe there is some way to copy the file in a hot. If I have to do any change, I have to do a restart of the server and sometimes, I have to do a maven clean install to clean it up.

Comment: Only exploded war will work for hot deployment, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: Indeed. Not sure about IntelliJ but Eclipse does that automatically when the referenced fragment project is in same workspace. This is by the way not strictly a JSF problem, just a tooling problem. You would have faced exactly the same problem when using any other web framework in this setup like Spring MVC, Struts, plain JSP/Servlet, etc, hence I removed the misleading [jsf] tags from the question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, I have the war exploded.

Comment: @BalusC probably it's the IDE problem, but I don't know how to configure IntelliJ to deploy in hot redeploy. Can you tell me some tips about it?

Comment: As said, I'm not sure. I don't use it.

Comment: Finally I saw that the files are hot swapped in a good way. On the other hand, I can see the files are changed, but it is not the case on seeing the results on the webpage. There is a cache by default on Primefaces or JSF2 to avoid reload the JAR files when are changed?